# What happens when play with constraints

Tags: sql-server, constraint, check-constraints

I'm inserting data from one DB to one other on another instance by using the following method:

- Create insert into scripts from the source DB.
- TargetDB: DROP constraints, insert data and Create Constraints again;

Is the inserted data already in connection with those constraints or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The reason why I am doing this is to move away from a partitioned database to a non-partitioned database (Enterprise to Standard Edition)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Drop Index and Reccreate it did the trick for me.

Comment: What do indexes have to do with (dropping and recreating) constraints?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is disable the constraints on the table instead of dropping them, and then re-enable them once done.

For SQL Server:

```
-- Disable all the constraint in database
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- Enable all the constraint in database
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Comment: Worth noting that `sp_msforeachtable` is undocumented so it may not be ideal to use if this is going into an automated process against production or the like.